# Rails 2.2 translation plugin/gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, translation, globalize2

I'm looking for a localisation system to use in a rails 2.2.2 app that i manage.  I think i've seen one before that does exactly what i want but i can't manage to find it with google.

The system i have in mind works as follows:  any ActiveRecord model (or perhaps a list of specified models, listed in a config file for example) can have a translation record associated with it, which specifies a locale and the new values for one or more of the fields in that record, for the listed locale.  Please note this is a seperate sort of problem to that solved by i18n: it's a way of setting locale-specific data, rather than locale-specific names of fields or similar "system-level" strings.

For example, let's say my site provides music lessons.  In the UK (the default locale), musical notes which last one "beat" are called "crotchets"* while in the US they're called "quarter notes".  So, i might have a lesson that has this data:

```
#a Lesson object, with an entry in the "lessons" table in the db
id: 1234
name: "My Lesson"
description: "In this lesson you'll learn about crotchets."
```

and I want this translation record associated with it:

```
id: 1
translatable_type: "Lesson"
translatable_id: 1234
locale: "US"
data: {:description => "In this lesson you'll learn about quarter notes"}
```

Now, when i view the lesson, the system checks the current locale, and sees if there's any current-locale-specific data for this lesson, sees that there is (the description) and displays that instead of the standard description.

Has anyone seen a system like this?

thanks, max

PS - in this example i've done a simple string substitution of "crotchets" to "quarter notes", which might tempt the reader to think i just need some kind of simple string substitution translation.  But that's not the case - some of the US-specific names/descriptions will be quite different to their uk counterparts and so require a completely customisable us-facing name, description, etc.

*this might not be exactly musically true in all cases but that's outside the scope of this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [Globalize2](https://github.com/joshmh/globalize2) may be what you are after for locale-specific data solutions (I've had success using [Globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) for my Rails 3.2 apps).  If not, then hopefully the [alternative solutions section](https://github.com/joshmh/globalize2#alternative-solutions) on Globalize2's Github repo README file will provide something else that will work for you with Rails 2.2.  Good luck!

Comment: Just what i was looking for, thanks Paul :)  And it seems to work fine with rails 2.2.2 (I had I18n installed already)